# Create a Python type from C that implements a __dict__?

Tags: python, c, types, python-3.x, python-c-api

- How is a type created to have a `__dict__` as per a "normal" class would have were it defined in Python?
- Are there any examples of non-dynamic types with `__dict__`s?
- Do types defined via Python's [`PyTypeObject`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Include/object.h?view=markup&sortby=date) pass through [`type_new`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/py3k/Objects/typeobject.c?view=markup&sortby=date)?

There is a `tp_dict` member of `PyTypeObject`, but I can find no information on how it's used. There also seems to be something going on in `typeobject.c`'s `type_new` but I can't decipher it clearly.

Here is some related information I've found:

- [`__dict__` in class inherited from C extension module](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t357472-__dict__-in-class-inherited-from-c-extension-module.html)
- [How is __slots__ implemented in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057845/149482)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code will generate a class that implements a `__dict__` in Python 2.x:

```
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD
  PyObject* dict;
} BarObject;

static PyTypeObject BarObject_Type = {
  PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initFoo(void)
{
  PyObject *m;

  m = Py_InitModule("Foo", NULL);
  if (m == NULL)
    return;

  BarObject_Type.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
  BarObject_Type.tp_name = "Foo.Bar";
  BarObject_Type.tp_basicsize = sizeof(BarObject);
  BarObject_Type.tp_getattro = PyObject_GenericGetAttr;
  BarObject_Type.tp_setattro = PyObject_GenericSetAttr;
  BarObject_Type.tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT;
  BarObject_Type.tp_dictoffset = offsetof(BarObject,dict);
  BarObject_Type.tp_doc = "Doc string for class Bar in module Foo.";
  if (PyType_Ready(&BarObject_Type) < 0)
    return;

  Py_INCREF(&BarObject_Type);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "Bar", (PyObject*)&BarObject_Type);
}
```

The important bit is the `tp_dictoffset` member of the `PyTypeObject` struct (http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html):

> If the instances of this type have a dictionary containing instance
>   variables, this field is non-zero and contains the offset in the
>   instances of the type of the instance variable dictionary; this offset
>   is used by PyObject_GenericGetAttr().
>
> Do not confuse this field with tp_dict; that is the dictionary for
>   attributes of the type object itself.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the last question first: No, `type_new` is only used for "heap types" that are dynamically defined at runtime (e.g. via a class statement). Statically defined types are initialised using `PyType_Ready()` instead.

To answer your first question: to create an extension type with a `__dict__` descriptor, you need to dynamically allocate the type the same way the interpreter does for a class definition.

One way to get examples for that is to do as John suggests and generate some examples of your own with Cython.

For CPython 2.x you can look at the `build_class` method in the CPython source code (http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Python/ceval.c?view=markup) to get an idea of the steps involved in a fully general solution.

If you're using Python 3 though, then this question may be of interest: [What does Python's builtin __build_class__ do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832997/what-does-pythons-builtin-build-class-do)

That is, as a CPython 3.x specific solution, the simplest thing to do is call `builtins.__build_class__` with appropriate arguments via the C API.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this, I'm embarrasingly bad on using the C-API, but according to the docs it should be enough with using `PyObject_GenericGetAttr` and `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` for the `getattro` and `setattro` methods. You also need to have a PyObject attribute called `__dict__` of course.

Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

How about writing some Python code defining a class and a method or two, compiling it with Cython and inspecting the generated C code?

Comment: That might indeed be helpful, but the C code Cython generates is both big and hard to introspect, as is common with automatically generated code. (Not my -1, though. But anyway).

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: You don't need to introspect it, just inspect it for big words starting with Py.

Comment: You know, I did that, and it didn't really tell me much. :)