# CPython - Adding an attribute to a new type that contains a __dict__

Tags: python, attributes, cpython

I know you can add Writables members with:

> struct PyMemberDef * PyTypeObject.tp_members

But I do not want to limit myself to a specific amount of attributes. So I created an object with ***__dict__*** according to Andrew Floren solution: [Create a Python type from C that implements a __dict__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061251/create-a-python-type-from-c-that-implements-a-dict)

I can now add attributes in Python, but what if I want to add an attribute in C?
How to add an attribute to an object with ***__dict__*** in C?

**PyObject with __dict __...**

```
typedef struct {
  PyObject_HEAD
  PyObject* dict;
} BarObject;

static PyTypeObject BarObject_Type = {
  PyObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL)
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initFoo(void)
{
  PyObject *m;

  m = Py_InitModule("Foo", NULL);
  if (m == NULL)
    return;

  BarObject_Type.tp_new = PyType_GenericNew;
  BarObject_Type.tp_name = "Foo.Bar";
  BarObject_Type.tp_basicsize = sizeof(BarObject);
  BarObject_Type.tp_getattro = PyObject_GenericGetAttr;
  BarObject_Type.tp_setattro = PyObject_GenericSetAttr;
  BarObject_Type.tp_flags = Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT;
  BarObject_Type.tp_dictoffset = offsetof(BarObject,dict);
  BarObject_Type.tp_doc = "Doc string for class Bar in module Foo.";
  if (PyType_Ready(&BarObject_Type) < 0)
    return;

  Py_INCREF(&BarObject_Type);
  PyModule_AddObject(m, "Bar", (PyObject*)&BarObject_Type);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
Basically the dict offset must be a PyObject of type dict

```
BarObject *bar = PyObject_New(BarObject, &BarObject_Type);
bar->dict = PyDict_New();
PyObject_SetAttrString((PyObject*)bar, "none", Py_None);
```

Comment: But for some reason the "none" does not appear in dir(bar). Why?

Comment: Please add some explanation. Imparting the underlying logic is more important than just giving the code, because it helps the OP and other readers fix this and similar issues themselves